# Updating md-maxlength value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

When I update the "item.MaxLength" value it does not affect the output and still shows the original value as md-maxlength. What is wrong with my code? thanks.

Input-1: I expect it to change md-maxlength value accoding to "input-2"

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.Desc" md-maxlength="{{item.MaxLength}}">
```

Input-2: That I want to control the input-1 md-maxlength with "item.MaxLength"

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.MaxLength">
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? In md-maxlength you should give number string to which you want maximum character for field. why you're having it same variable name as with the ng-model?

Comment: ok. I edited my question to make it clear. I had written the fastest way. I want to control md-maxlength of input-1 by updating input-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's hardly a way to update md-maxlength value dynamically. But there's workaround for your issue. You can just delete & re-render the input element after changing the value of length setting field. add `ng-if` on `md-input-container` & change its value accordingly change in length field by using $watch or using ng-change function on length field.

```
<md-input-container ng-if="showN">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input  type="text" md-maxlength='{{view.len}}' ng-model="view.name" />
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <label>Len</label>
    <input type="number"  ng-model="view.len" />
</md-input-container>
```

And in controller have:

```
$scope.$watch('view.len', function(n,o){
    $scope.showN = false;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.showN = true;
    });
});
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fLh0VfuTUjjmGo8PRioy?p=preview